# Grafana: How To Use $__timeFilter in a Grafana Query Variable

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, grafana, grafana-variable

I'm trying to create a variable in Grafana that will pull distinct servers from a BigQuery database. I would like to only pull these servers from within a given time window like one would normally with something like WHERE $__timeFilter(timestamp). Is it possible to use global variables within a query variable? I can't seem to find any documentation around this. For reference, I'm currently using

This query to get a list of all servers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT server FROM table WHERE timetamp < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Whereas I would like to use something like this to get a list of servers within the time window the user selects in Grafana:

```
SELECT DISTINCT server FROM table WHERE $__timeFilter(timestamp)
```

Comment: Why you don't use troubleshooting guide https://github.com/doitintl/bigquery-grafana#troubleshooting ?

Comment: @JanGaraj It looks like the query inspector that they're using is within the panel creation, where using $__timeFilter works fine and doesn't throw an error. When you are creating a variable from a bigquery data source you can't use the query inspector (nor any way of trouble shooting from what I can tell).

Comment: You can use network console to see how macros are interpolated. But I guess macros are not supported in the dashboard variable queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `date_column` is your date column in `table`, in the Google BigQuery's standard `DATE` format, you should convert it into a `TIMESTAMP` and then apply `$__timeFilter`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT server FROM table WHERE $__timeFilter(TIMESTAMP(date_column))
```